# How do I remove a property from Azure Table Storage with powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell

I tried this code to remove property from table:

```
$propertiesToRemove = @("Prop1", "Prop2")
$row = Get-AzTableRow -Table $cloudTable -PartitionKey "PK" -RowKey $id
$propertiesToRemove | %{ $row.PSObject.Properties.Remove($_) }
Update-AzTableRow -Table $cloudTable -entity $row
```

but it leaves them untouched. How do I do this with powershell?

Comment: I would use: [`Select-Object -ExludeProperty $propertiesToRemove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7#parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using [`AzureRmStorageTable`](https://github.com/paulomarquesc/AzureRmStorageTable), I don't think it is possible to remove properties from a table because `Update-AzTableRow` performs an [`InsertOrMerge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-or-merge-entity) operation instead of either [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/update-entity2) or [`InsertOrReplace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-or-replace-entity) operation.

From the [`source code`](https://github.com/paulomarquesc/AzureRmStorageTable/blob/master/AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1#L614):

```
return ($Table.Execute([Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableOperation]::InsertOrMerge($updatedEntity)))
```